# The Differential Equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=60(y^2)^{1/5}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> The Differential Equation
>
> $$\frac{dy}{dx}=60(y^2)^{1/5}$$
>
> $x>0$, $y(0)=0$, has
>
> 1. a unique solution,
> 2. two solutions,
> 3. no solution,
> 4. infinite number of solutions.

After solving I got that $\frac{5}{3}y^{3/5}= 60 x+c$, where $c$ is constant. Then after putting $y(0)=0$ we getting $y^{3/5}=100x$. Since constant is absent in the solution then  option 3 and 4 is not true. Then which option will be correct?

Answer (score 2):

Option (4): Try the functions $y$ defined by $y(x)=0$ if $x\leqslant x_0$ and by $y(x)=c\cdot(x-x_0)^{5/3}$ if $x\gt x_0$, for any $x_0\geqslant0$, for some suitable $c$.

Comment: I did't get you. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Sure. What did you not get in my answer?

Comment: You are saying that option (4) is correct. But in my solution arbitrary constant is vanished.So how there will be infinite number  of solutions ?

Comment: Hmmm... Did you even read my answer? It is not that long and, who knows, you might find in it some elements to help your thinking about the question, for example, say... "infinite[ly many] solutions".

Comment: @Sayan: your method won't give the most general solution.  You have made the assumption that both sides may be divided by the expression on the right.  But you can't always divide by an expression...  What if there were solutions for which that division was not well defined?